# Prolog - for all implication

Tags: prolog, logic

How can I represent a for-all implication in Prolog?

In logic:

```
x is given

For all a, b . [P(a) AND P(b) AND P(x) ---> Q(a,b)]
```

The prolog would be

```
pred(X) :- ....
```

Comment: `q(A,B) :- p(A), p(B), p(x).`

Comment: SWI has `forall/2` also, by the way.

Comment: @mbratch: But then it isn't over all A and B with x fixed?

Comment: Why isn't it? That clause says, for any `A` and `B`, if `p(A)`, `p(B), and `p(x)` are true, then `q(A,B)` is true.

Comment: I need x to be a parameter of the predicate though

Comment: You said "x is given". If you want it a parameter, then you can say, `q(A,B,X) :- p(A), p(B), p(X).`.

Comment: but then whatever clause calls q(A,B,X) would need to know A and B, where as it wants to know whether for a specific X, if there is an A and B that makes P(a) and P(b) true then Q(a,b) is also true.

Comment: No, that's not exactly the case. In prolog, you can query, `q(A,B,x)` for instance, and it will tell you all the A's and B's which make it true. Maybe I'm not following what your specific use case is. And you can use the `forall/2` predicate mentioned by @DanielLyons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rewrite your formula into

```
not exists A,B . not (p(A) and p(B) and p(X) -> q(A,B)).
```

and further into

```
not exists A,B . (p(A) and p(B) and p(X) and not q(A,B)).
```

and then use that in your Prolog clause like

```
pred(X) :- \+ ( p(A), p(B), p(X), \+q(A,B) ).
```

As mentioned by others, some Prologs define a shorthand for this, called forall/2, so you should be able to use

```
pred(X) :- forall((p(A), p(B), p(X)), q(A,B)).
```

Comment: Ah that's more on track than what I was thinking (+1).

Comment: You have to admit, it's pretty sexy how close that last line is to the original question. +1